# Optimizing Black & White Filter in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, filter, rgb

I have implemented a method that applies Black & White over an image and I would like to know what would be the best alternative of the same algorithm but using Threads ?

```
public static void blackAndWhite()
{
        for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                int rgb = Main.img.getRGB(x, y);
                Color c = new Color(rgb);
                int grey = (int) (0.299 * c.getRed() + 0.587 * c.getGreen() + 0.114*c.getBlue());
                Color c2 = new Color(grey, grey, grey);
                Main.img.setRGB(x, y, c2.getRGB());
            }
        }

}
```

I thought of doing something like this but I get errors regarding 'final' status of x or y

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                int rgb = Main.img.getRGB(x, y);
                Color c = new Color(rgb);
                int grey = (int) (0.299 * c.getRed() + 0.587 * c.getGreen() + 0.114*c.getBlue());
                Color c2 = new Color(grey, grey, grey);
                Main.img.setRGB(x, y, c2.getRGB());
            }
        }
        });
        t.start();
        try{
            t.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
        }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Are you trying to use threads to convert multiple images or a single image?

Comment: Which version of Java do you use? In newer versions there is concept of variable being effectively final, upgrade may help you.